# If cell contains checkbox, determine if checkbox is ticked

Tags: vba, excel

I have 100+ files that my macro cycles through to collect data from

The macro searches for a specific string in each file and if the string is found takes data from the cell adjacent and copies it to a Master Workbook.

Some of the cells adjacent contain checkboxes.  I want to be able to determine if the checkbox is ticked (none of the checkboxes are cell linked)

From what i've read to find if the check box is ticked I need to know the checkbox name.

Is it possible to check if the cell has a checkbox and then find the name of that checkbox?

Comment: You have to access the TopLeftCell property of the given checkbox and compare this range against the one you want. What you might do right at the start is going through all the checkboxes in the worksheet and store the respective TopLeftCell ranges in an array (together with its name), such that you can easily retrieve this information at a later stage.

Comment: Nice thinking! unfortunately it doesn't quite work, I tested it out but the checkboxes arn't sized within a specific cell.  So, for example, a check box may be in the cell adjacent to the string i'm searching for but the TopLeftCell property for that check box will return the range of the cell above.  Any other ideas?

Comment: This is the only way through. Checkboxes are not associated to specific cells (they can occupy more than one cell), TopLeftCell is the way to relate a checkbox to a given cell. From the TopLeftCell, you can retrieve the address (for example, "D16") and from this address you can determine if your cell (for example "C5") is close enough or not. Create a function taking as input the given cell and going through all the stored checkbox-ranges (addresses) to find out the closest one. Other alternative might be creating the checkboxes at runtime and thus knowing the TopLeftCells without pre-check.

Comment: Both checkbox and range have a Left and Top property. So you can match box and range using their absolute position.